Can't connect to mysql container when create user with @'localhost'?
I'm a newbie who recently learned docker. This question is forward from this question on SO.
My problem is that I can not connect mysql container running on my computer.
I created a MySQL container running on my machine and mapped port 3306 in the container to port 2223 in my machine like the command below:
docker run -d --name mysqlContainer -p 2223:3306 mysql:latest -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123

after that I create bash running within the container to create MySQL user by the following command:
docker exec -it mysqlContainer  bash

mysql -u root -p123

create USER 'badman'@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY '123';
create USER 'ironman'@"%" IDENTIFIED BY '123';

when I'm in the bash shell of the container and use two users created above to connect to MySQL, everything is good.
However, when I use SQLTools on my laptop (localhost) which host the MySQL container to connect into, only ironman user running. badman user can not connect to the container.
Before asking the question in this forum, I googled a lot to find the reason why? I also understand that:

@'%': wildcard allows the user to connect from any host
@'localhost': restricts access to the MySQL server from the same machine.

I have wonder why I can't connect to MySQL container (by badman user) when I use the machine (localhost) itself host MySQL container.
the following jsons are connection setting of badman and ironman:
badman:
{
  "mysqlOptions": {
    "authProtocol": "default",
    "enableSsl": "Disabled"
  },
  "previewLimit": 50,
  "server": "localhost",
  "port": 2223,
  "driver": "MySQL",
  "username": "badman",
  "password": "123",
  "name": "connect_badman"
}

{
  "mysqlOptions": {
    "authProtocol": "default",
    "enableSsl": "Disabled"
  },
  "previewLimit": 50,
  "server": "localhost",
  "port": 2223,
  "driver": "MySQL",
  "name": "usertest_ironman",
  "username": "ironman",
  "password": "123",
}


Connections from your host machine through port mapping are routed through Docker's bridge network and appear as external traffic.
